# How do I count by grouping a value without other select terms influencing the count? (self-join)

Tags: sql, select, group-by, self, self-join

So, I want to show which employees (names) have subordinates and how many subordinates they have (I was using self-join).
It works fine if I use count and group by looking at the "manager_id" colum which tells us who the employees boss is.
But as soon as I try to add to show the names of my selected bosses (not just their id), it messes up the count, saying that they all have just one subordinate.

I tried using group by, but it just tells me that they all have 1 subordinate.

```
`select e.first_name,e.last_name,count(e.manager_id) as 'Broj zaposlenika'
from  sales.staffs e left join sales.staffs m 
on m.staff_id=e.manager_id
where e.staff_id in (select e.manager_id from  sales.staffs e left join sales.staffs m 
on m.staff_id=e.manager_id)
group by e.manager_id, e.last_name,e.first_name;`
```

This one displays the correct number of employees, but as soon as I try putting the names in again, the count (number of emplyees gets messed up).

`select e.manager_id,count(e.manager_id) as 'Broj zaposlenika' from  sales.staffs e left join sales.staffs m  on m.staff_id=e.manager_id group by e.manager_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in the provided query is that it is grouping by employee name(e.first_name, e.last_time). But it should be grouping by **manager name(m.first_name, m.last_time)**.

Change the [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) condition to the following (e.manager_id, m.first_name, m.last_time) will make it work.

Here is the query:

```
select
    m.first_name,
    m.last_name,
    count(e.manager_id) as 'Broj zaposlenika' 
from  
    sales.staffs e 
left join 
    sales.staffs m  
on 
    m.staff_id=e.manager_id 
group by 
    e.manager_id, 
    m.first_name, 
    m.last_name
```